# IASKButtonSpecifiers don't get titles but everything else does

Tags: ios, inappsettingskit

Basically trying to copy the InAppSettingsKit demo code into my project to try it out.

I added a switch, a group and two IASKButtonSpecifiers. Everything works and my method gets called when i click the specifiers.

HOWEVER, they have not title, they are completely white. The group title and the switch get proper texts.

I tried changing the "type" of the switch setting into a button and the title then vanished there too, so it has to be something with the IASKButtonSpecifier type that is the problem.

I can't understand why, i copied it from the demo project and it works there.

EDIT this is how i create the controller. I add its view to a view in one of my tabs. Could that be an issue?

```
self.iAskAppSettingsViewController = [[IASKAppSettingsViewController alloc] init];
iAskAppSettingsViewController.delegate = self;
iAskAppSettingsViewController.showDoneButton = NO;
[mainView addSubview:iAskAppSettingsViewController.view];
```

Root.plist:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>enable</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>ENABLED_TITLE</string>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>IASKButtonSpecifier</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>ButtonDemoAction2</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Login</string>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>IASKButtonSpecifier</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>TEST_GROUP_TITLE</string>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <string>YES</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>toggleSwitch</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>REMINDER_TITLE</string>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSToggleSwitchSpecifier</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>StringsTable</key>
    <string>Root</string>
</dict>
```

Root.strings:

```
"ENABLED_TITLE" = "Bananas!";
"Login" = "The Ninja.";
"REMINDER_TITLE" = "Remember!";
"TEST_GROUP_TITLE" = "This is a group.";
```

Comment: Is it a localization problem, so does the title show up when you remove the `"Login" = "The Ninja.";` line in `Root.strings`?

Comment: Also, usually you want to embed IASK into a navigation controller. At least that's required if you have any child or multi value elements. But I doubt your problem has anything to do with this.

Comment: I have added the navigation controller. The reason for my setup was that i wanted some other gui components above the settingskit in my tab, i.e. i didn't want the settingskit table to take up the entire tab. It works if i add the settingskit controller directly in the tab.

Comment: Its not a localization issue i've tried that. I think its something with me adding the view for the controller as a subview to the view of "my" controller, if that makes any sense...

Comment: So you're saying that it works as long as IASK is in a navigation controller by its own?

Comment: yup. drove me nuts, couldn't make it work. It works when i add it directly into the tab in the tabcontroller, so i had to do that.

Comment: OK, good to know. Not sure exactly why it fails here but IASK really is meant to be embedded into a navigation controller, so everything else is unsupported territory. ;-)